# How do I communicate between Unity and an aws lambda function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, aws-lambda

I have a working `UnityWebRequest` in Unity...

```
private static void SendMessageToServerless(MessageBase message) {
    string uri = "https://urigoeshere.com/test";

    Get(uri, message);
}

private static void Get(string uri, MessageBase message) {
    instance.StartCoroutine(GetRequest(uri, message));
}

private static IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri, MessageBase message) {
    // TODO: Do something with message
    UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);
    yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

    Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
}
```

... and separately I have a working C# lambda on AWS ...

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
namespace SwordPlayServerless {
    public class Function {
        public string FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context) {
            return "Hello " + input;
        }
    }
}
```

... however I'm not sure how to bridge the gap and send typed content from one to the other. I commonly get the following error message in reply:

```
{
  "errorType": "JsonSerializerException",
  "errorMessage": "Error converting the Lambda event JSON payload to a string. JSON strings must be quoted, for example \"Hello World\" in order to be converted to a string: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.",
  ...
```

Comment: from what the error says I'm just guessing but it probably should be a json formatted string like `return "{ \"value\" : \"Hello " + input + "\" }"`

Comment: If I send string input directly to the lambda through the AWS interface it works correctly and returns `"Hello <input>"`. It looks like the error is on the lambda side. It can't read what we're sending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending json-data you need to set up the lambda function to expect `JObject` as an input. You can then cast the json into any suitable object inbound or outbound:

```csh
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public JObject FunctionHandler(JObject jsonContent, ILambdaContext context) {
    Message clientMessage = jsonContent.ToObject<Message>();
    // ...
    Message response = new Message();
    return JObject.FromObject(response);
}
```

Unity has support for JSON built in. My original code was close...

```csh
private static void SendMessageToServerless(Message message) {
    string uri = "https://example.com/test";

    instance.StartCoroutine(SendMessageToServerlessAsync(uri, message));
}

private static IEnumerator SendMessageToServerlessAsync(string uri, Message message) {
    UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Put(uri, JsonUtility.ToJson(message));
    yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

    if (webRequest.isNetworkError) {
        Debug.LogError("Network error: " + webRequest.error);
    } else { 
        Message response = JsonUtility.FromJson<Message>(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        Debug.Log(response.statusCode);
    }
}
```

In this way both the server and client can use the same definition for the `Message` class so long as it is serializable.